# Определение нового типа

Tags: c, типы-данных

Могу ли я определить в Си новый тип, но так, чтобы передача переменной базового типа вызывала ошибку компиляции? Или хотя бы выдавала предупреждение?

Что-то типа такого

```
typedef int newInt;

void test1(int arg) {}
void test2(newInt arg) {}

int test3() {return 0;}
newInt test4() {return 0;}

int x = 0;
test2(x);  // Ошибка. Нужен тип newInt

newInt nx = 0;
test1(nx);  // Ошибка. Нужен тип int

x = test4();  // Ошибка. Нужен тип newInt
nx = test4();  // Ошибка. Нужен тип int
```

Все до чего додумался, это определение структуры

```
typedef struct {int x;} newInt;
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, ньютайпов в си нет.  Только через структуру.

Comment: typedef не создает новый тип, формально в примере вы создали псевдоним для int.

Comment: @Bat1stuff вопрос - как получить ошибку компиляции

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но всегда казалось, что в С это прерогатива компилятора и его настроек. Пожалуйста, если найдете ответ - напишите.

Comment: Если вы будете развивать эту тему, то рано, или поздно создадите С++, который изначально так и назывался С с типами (классами), созревший до С++ :) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/history-of-c/#:~:targetText=C%2B%2B%20was%20initially%20known%20as,%E2%80%9Cone%20higher%20than%20C.%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандарте (точнее, в его публично доступном
[наброске](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))
функция класса `typedef` определена явно; см.
**§6.7.8 п.3**:

> (…) A `typedef` declaration does not introduce a new type,
> only a synonym for the type so specified.  (…)

То есть, это синоним, а не новый тип.

Ваш вариант со структурой вполне резонен, хотя программист всё ещё может
обратиться напрямую к значению.  Если вам необходимо скрыть реализацию
полностью без перехода на *C++*, то наверное лучшее, что вы можете
сделать — это «приватная структура»:

- `metres.h`:

  ```c
  typedef struct metres metres_t;

  int       metres_get_value(metres_t *x);
  metres_t *metres_add(metres_t *x, metres_t *y);
  metres_t *metres_new(int value);
  void      metres_delete(metres_t *x);
  ```
- `metres.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdlib.h>
  // NULL
  // free
  // malloc

  #include "metres.h"

  struct metres {
      int value;
  };

  int metres_get_value(metres_t *x)
  {
      if (x == NULL) {
          return 0;
      }

      return x->value;
  }

  metres_t *metres_add(metres_t *x, metres_t *y)
  {
      if (x == NULL || y == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }

      metres_t *z = malloc(sizeof(metres_t));
      if (z == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }

      z->value = x->value + y->value;
      return z;
  }

  metres_t *metres_new(int value)
  {
      metres_t *x = malloc(sizeof(metres_t));
      if (x == NULL) {
          return NULL;
      }

      x->value = value;
      return x;
  }

  void metres_delete(metres_t *x)
  {
      free(x);
  }
  ```
- `main.c`:

  ```c
  #include <stdio.h>
  // printf

  #include "metres.h"
  // metres_add
  // metres_delete
  // metres_get_value
  // metres_new
  // metres_t

  int main(void)
  {
      metres_t *x = metres_new(5);
      metres_t *y = metres_new(4);
      metres_t *z = metres_add(x, y);

      printf("the result is: %dm\n", metres_get_value(z));

      metres_delete(x);
      metres_delete(y);
      metres_delete(z);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Заметьте, что подобный шаблон заставляет вас и программиста «мучаться»
с указателями, так как программист видит лишь неполное определение
`typedef struct metres metres_t`, что не позволяет ему
пользоваться автоматическим выделением памяти (стеком).  Скорее всего,
для большинства случаев это перебор, и достаточно вашего решения
с простой структурой.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ